# Issue attaching a onClick handler with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to remove the 'ui-btn-active' class from this JQuery Mobile markup piece:

```
<a id="btnFree" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-top ui-btn-up-a ui-btn-active"
 onclick="setStatus('free')" data-icon="alert" data-iconpos="top"
 data-role="button" href="#" data-theme="a">

   <span class="ui-btn-inner">
   <span class="ui-btn-text">Free</span>
   <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-shadow ui-icon-check"></span>
   </span>
</a>
```

I'm using this as the onclick function but the last line doesn't work:

```
function setStatus() {
    $("#btnFree").children('span.ui-btn-inner').children('span.ui-icon').removeClass('ui-icon-alert');
    $("#btnFree").children('span.ui-btn-inner').children('span.ui-icon').addClass('ui-icon-check');
    $("#btnFree").removeClass('ui-btn-active');
    }
```

By looking at Firebug it doesn't seem to change anything. Other instructions in the function work fine, so I don't know what I'm missing. Any hints?

The actual code I wrote is the following, which gets translated to the above by JQM:

```
<div data-role="navbar" id="nvb1">
   <ul>
     <li><a href='#' data-role="button" id="btnFree" data-iconpos="top" data-icon="alert" onClick="setStatus('free')">Free</a></li>
     <li><a href='#' data-role="button" id="btnBusy" data-iconpos="top" onClick="setStatus('busy')">Busy</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

What I'm actually trying to accomplish, is preventing a clicked button in a navbar to become highlighted.

Comment: If that's your actual code, your span tag is malformed (missing the closing tag). This could cause the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: sorry, added the missing part.

Comment: Make sure there aren't any another elements with the same id.

Comment: can you confirm that the intended onclick function is being called when you click the link?

Comment: yes it is. I added the full function, whose 2 other commands are executed successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code seems to work fine:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="navbar" id="nvb1">
   <ul>
     <li><a href='#' data-role="button" id="btnFree" data-iconpos="top" data-icon="alert">Free</a></li>
     <li><a href='#' data-role="button" id="btnBusy" data-iconpos="top" onClick="setStatus('busy')">Busy</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
</div>
​<script>
$("#btnFree").live("click tap", function() {
    $("#btnFree").children('span.ui-btn-inner').children('span.ui-icon').removeClass('ui-icon-alert');
    $("#btnFree").children('span.ui-btn-inner').children('span.ui-icon').addClass('ui-icon-check');
    $("#btnFree").removeClass('ui-btn-active');
});​
</script>​​​​​​
```

Try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/R8ZCW/8/).

The trick is using the .live() method, which will attach a persistent event handler. Also note that it will capture both the click and tap events (since I presume you are developing a mobile app).

Comment: Looks like a very effective idea, but it doesn't seem to work if JQM is used.

Comment: What doesn't work? What did you do, expect, and see? I'm not sure that I can help you without more information.

Comment: I launch the page in firefox, click the btnFree button but ui-btn-active isn't removed, i.e. the button is still highlighted and firebug still show the class there. I guess the class gets added after my removal attempt? Plus, I added the #btnFree.ui-btn-active css block as you suggested but it seems to be overidden.

Comment: Please try the adjusted sample, which implements JQM.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior for JQM is to set the ui-btn-active class when you click the navbar button. To keep JQM from setting it, you need to stop the event from propagating.

```
    $('#nvb1 a').bind('click', function(e) {

        var $btn = $(this);
        $('#status').html('Status is: ' + $btn.data('status'));

        // tell JQM that you handled the event
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

I've created a sample here. http://jsfiddle.net/kiliman/d7MvN/